# C and hashlib LNK errors

Tags: .net, hash, c++-cli, linker-errors, sha1

Okay. So i am using Visual Studios 2010 -> Visual C++ and the .NET Framework (Windows Forms Application) and when i try to hash a string with the hashlib++ i get multiple LNK errors.

This is hashlib++ : http://hashlib2plus.sourceforge.net/

This is my code for the hash:

```
//I have more Includes but according to http://hashlib2plus.sourceforge.net/example.html these are the only ones required for hashlib++ so these are the ones i am putting on display.
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <hashlibpp.h>

//I skipped adding namespaces to my display code

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

                 try{
                     String^ atmp_user = textBox1->Text;
                     String^ user = (myReader->GetString(1));//Connecting to MySQL Databases and grabbing usernames
                     String^ atmp_pass = textBox2->Text;
                     String^ pass = (myReader->GetString(2));
                     atmp_pass->ToLower();//LowerCase
                     atmp_user->ToLower();
                     String^ total1 = gcnew String(atmp_user+atmp_pass);

                     string totala;

                     MarshalString(total1, totala);//Converting String^ to an std::string

                     hashwrapper *myWrapper = new sha1wrapper();//SHA1 code begins

         string hash1 = myWrapper->getHashFromString(totala);

 delete myWrapper;//SHA1 code ends

                     if(atmp_user == user && hash1 == pass){
                         textBox1->Text = ("It worked!");
                     }
                     }
                 } catch(Exception^ex) {
                     MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
                 }
         }
```

This is my error log:

```
Error   2   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00001E) "public: __clrcall sha1wrapper::sha1wrapper(void)" (??0sha1wrapper@@$$FQAM@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Launcher::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@Launcher@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)   C:\Users\Jeremy\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Launcher\Launcher\Launcher.obj
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __clrcall sha1wrapper::sha1wrapper(void)" (??0sha1wrapper@@$$FQAM@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Launcher::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@Launcher@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)    C:\Users\Jeremy\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Launcher\Launcher\Launcher.obj
Error   4   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Jeremy\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Launcher\Release\Launcher.exe
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated guys. :) I have been working very hard on just creating a secure login script for the past few days. I keep running into LNK errors everywhere i go. :\

Comment: I retagged this from C++ to C++-CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I had to turn off precompiled headers.